# Robot Framework: get element by text

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I'm testing a website which is not exactly designed for automation testing. I'm using Robot Framework, Selenium2Library. There's an element that I cannot locate it by `x-path` the web driver will always locate to another element. Is there anyway to get the element by its text ?

The example HTML looks like

```
<label>Next Steps</label>
```

Is there any additional library that allows something like

```
Get Element By Text  Next Steps
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that element by text using xPath as well:

```
//label[text()="Next Steps"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    //label[.='Next Steps']
```

Recommended pages:

- https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html
- https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/Selenium2Library.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

Wait until element is visible, set focus and then get element by text :

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    //label[text()="Next Steps"]    timeout=${time}s
Set Focus To Element    //label[text()="Next Steps"]    
Get Text    //label[text()="Next Steps"]
```

Comment: There is no `Get Element By Text` keyword